# jquery-ui-map and MarkerClustererPlus => Get Click Event (on markerCluster) and fire another event

Tags: jquery, google-maps, onclick, markerclusterer, jquery-ui-map

I have a project, that uses jquery-map-ui and MarkerClustererPlus.

All works the way it should do - but one thing is missing:

Whenever the Map Center is changed (dragend) I am reloading the results (markers) via Ajax as well as displaying a classical result list of the 10 best entries underneath the Map (for "non visual users").

I would like to have the same thing to happen, when the user click on a Marker Cluster Button (the Map Center and the zoom are changed, but I cannot get a handle on this to fire my own event (reloading best result list based on the new Map Center) ...

So the question is: 
How can I get my function started, when someone click on a ClusterMarker and the map is recentered ... unfortunately the dragend event does not work here. Also played around with markerClusterer "click" function, but did not get it to work :-(

Here's what I am using right now ... based on:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/
and
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Update: Basically I am looking for a possibility / advice on how to embed the functions as shown here http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/examples/events_example.html
into my code:

```
$(function() 
{ 
    getMarkersByLatitudeAndLongitude(); //call function to load map and markers on initial load

    $('#map').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) 
    { 
        $(map).dragend(function() 
        {
            getMarkersByLatitudeAndLongitude(); //reload Map and Markers, if Map has been moved
        });

        $(map).addEventListener('zoom_changed', function() 
        {
      var initial_zoom = $('#map').gmap('option', 'zoom'); //reload Map & Markers, if Zoom level has been changed and if we need more results
      var new_zoom = $("#map").gmap('get', 'map').getZoom();
      if(new_zoom<=initial_zoom )   getMarkersByLatitudeAndLongitude(); 
        }); 
    });

    function getMarkersByLatitudeAndLongitude()
    {
        var latlng  = $("#map").gmap('get', 'map').getCenter();
        var zoom        = $("#map").gmap('get', 'map').getZoom();
        var i           = 0;
        $('#map').gmap('closeInfoWindow'); // close any open info window
        $('#map').gmap('clear', 'markers'); // remove all markers
        $('#map').gmap('get', 'MarkerClusterer').clearMarkers(); //remove all cluster markers

    //get results to be display via json
        $.getJSON( '/code/get_json_data.php', { 'latitude': latlng.lat(), 'longitude': latlng.lng() ,'zoom': zoom }, function(data) 
        { 
            if(data)
            {
                $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) 
                {
                    if(i<10) 
                    {
                        for_list    = for_list  + "|" + marker.id ; //remember the first 10 markers to be display in Details Results List under the Map
                        i++;
                    }
          $('#map').gmap('addMarker', 
                    { 
                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.la, marker.lo),
                        'icon':marker.m,
                        'title':marker.n,
            'bounds':false  
                    })
                    .click(function()
                    {
                        var content = load_content(marker.f);
                        $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow',{ 'content': content}, this); // get Marker Content on Click. function load_content gets the content via Ajax
                    });
                });

        // let Marker Clusterer do his work
                $('#map').gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer($('#map').gmap('get', 'map'), $('#map').gmap('get', 'markers'), {
            'maxZoom':12,   
          'gridSize': 45, 
          'title':'Click to zoom in'
        })); 


                //Load an generate the Detail List
        $.post('/code/get_details_for_list.php', { list: for_list } , function(data) {
                    $('#detail_list').html(data);
                });

                // add Marker for center position
        $('#map').gmap('addMarker', 
                { 
                    'position': latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng(),
                    'icon'      : '/code/geo/images/gmap_pin_blue.png',
                    'title'   : 'Center of your Search'
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Any tip in the right direction is highley appreciated. Would be enough, if I could manage to alert the new Map Center coordinates after the markerClusterer click event.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the MarkerClusterer as argument to `google.maps.event.addListener`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(
      $('#map').gmap('get', 'MarkerClusterer'),
      'click',
      function(){
      alert('click on cluster');
    });
```

Comment: Tried that but I have not succeeded ... where should that be called? Also tried the jquery-ui-map "version":
 $('#map').addEventListener($('#map').gmap('get', 'MarkerClusterer'),'click', function(){ alert('click on cluster'); });

Comment: You can call it somewhere as soon as the clusterer has been created. My code uses a wrong selector(#map_canvas instead of #map). Fixed it, please try again.

Comment: fixed it (also before) but will not work ... I guess it's because I am using jquery-ui-maps as well here

Comment: If you like, you can see the live version as well ... You are in Berlin, I am in Munich ...

Comment: Servus! show me the live-version(I'm sure that my suggestion works)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working with a "workaround".

I added a function call into the markercluster.js file into this function:  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "click", function (e) { .....

My function call updates my lists based on the new Map Center.

Maybe not the most intelligent solution, but it works ...